# part of the solution of a homogeneous linear equations

Tags: matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector.
we have
$$\boldsymbol{Ax} = 0.$$

We denote the first $n_1$ elements of $\boldsymbol{x}$ as $\boldsymbol{x}_1$, and the remaining part as $\boldsymbol{x}_2$. For the the partitions $\boldsymbol{x}^{T} = (\boldsymbol{x}_1^{T}, \boldsymbol{x}_2^{T})$,
$\boldsymbol{A}=(\boldsymbol{A_1}, \boldsymbol{A_2}),$
$$\boldsymbol{Ax = A_1x_1+A_2x_2=0}$$

If n>m, we can not conclude $\boldsymbol{x}=0$. We expect a conclusion for $\boldsymbol{x}_1=0$.

I am trying to figure out this question:
If $n_1<m$, under what conditions on A, we can conclude the first part $\boldsymbol{x}_1=0$?

Comment: "we can not conclude $\boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol0$": $\boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol0$ is *always* a solution.

Comment: thank you. I mean the solution may not be unique, so $x=0$ may not be necessary.
when (the rank of A)=n, $x=0$ is the unique solution. We can conclude from $Ax=0$ to $x=0$.
I want to know when n_1<(the rank of A)<n, under what conditions, the first part of the solution is always zero?